# Copy files from one folder to another on client side without ActiveX

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking a solution to copy a file from one location to another location in client side using javascript . I have found a solution using

```
var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

var file = object.GetFile(filePathsource);
file.Copy(destinationpath)

But I am looking a solution with pure javascript solution without Scripting.FileSystemObject that will work for browsers.

Any kind of help or solution that would resolve my issue.

Comment: Browsers do not provide direct access to client file systems.

Comment: Not possible under normal conditions. Imagine if any website in the world could access your hard drive directly and make changes without you having to confirm them.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with browser-based JavaScript cross-browser. You can read a file (by having the user identify it for you, via `input type="file"` or drag-and-drop) and using a `FileReader`, and you can offer to save a file within limits (with the user telling the browser where it should go, which your script wouldn't get access to) by using a blob or data URI with a download link, but you can't directly pick the file to read or where to write a file, for the obvious security reasons.